# Angular 2+ - how to multi provide values in a component tree?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, provider

Some time ago I ran into a challenge and I'm still unable to find a good solution for it.

I have a tree of components and I want every component to provide a value with the same token for every direct child component. Only their direct children needs to have that value, because it is irrelevant to other component further down the tree.

The first problem I ran into is that when I provide a value with a token both in a parent and child component, the child overwrites it before I could use the value coming from the parent. Overwriting wouldn't be problem, if I could somehow get the value provided by the parent component.

My first idea was to use a multi provider, so no provided value would be lost. However, it didn't work the way I imagined it would work between components. I made a little picture to illustrate what I experienced using the multi providers.

[The result of using multi providers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHiFX.png)

To me, this functionality makes no sense. Even though I used "multi: true", every provided value from the upper components got lost.
Before looking at the logs,
[this is how I imagined it would work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6VE6.png)

I injected the array like this:

```
constructor(@Inject('MultiToken') private multiProvidedValues: string[])
{...}
```

This way I would know that the last element in the array was provided by the current component, and the one before it was provided by the parent component.
If there is only one element, than the current component is the root.

Is it possible to use the multi providers in the way that my 2. picture shows?
Or could I somehow get the value coming from the parent, even though my component provides the same token?

In the end I managed to solve the problem by providing a map only in the root, but I really want to solve this using dependency injections.

Thank you in advance!